# Selecting only the filled controls and locking them

Tags: vb.net, locking

I need your help with partial locking of a record. This is the situation when there is a shift change and one record is started by one person and finished by another. What one has written another can’t change but must finished a record. So u must lock only the combo boxes and text boxes that are filled. This code lockes all the combo boxes and text boxes and 2 check boxes (NEZAVRSENE_INTERVENCIJE and IZMENA_RASKRSNICE) by clicking on a NEZAVRSENE_INTERVENCIJE check box. Lets say I have combo boxes 1 2 and 3 and text boxes 1 2 and 3 and I have to lock only the ones that are filled. How do I code that another check box lockes just the filled controls?

Thanks

```
Private Sub NEZAVRSENE_INTERVENCIJE_AfterUpdate()
Dim ctrl As Control

If Me.NEZAVRSENE_INTERVENCIJE = -1 Then

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Or (ctrl Is NEZAVRSENE_INTERVENCIJE) Or  (ctrl Is IZMENA_RASKRSNICE) Or (TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox) Then
 ctrl.Locked = True

End If
Next

Else

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Or (ctrl Is NEZAVRSENE_INTERVENCIJE) Or  (ctrl Is IZMENA_RASKRSNICE) Or (TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox) Then
  ctrl.Locked = False

End If
Next

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should clean up your logic some. You shouldn't use "Or" in this case as it will test every single one.

Comment: Why do you name your controls in ALL_CAPS?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  I am using the [Control.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property to group the Controls that you are wanting to lock.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If Not IsNothing(ctrl.Tag) Then
            If CInt(ctrl.Tag) = 1 Then
                If ctrl.Text <> String.Empty Then
                    ctrl.Enabled = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```